# View models and data bindings in Kotlin - getting error "cannot resolve class data"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android development, and I am trying to use a view model in my project. I have a `ViewModel` which fetches data from an API, and then I try to access this data from my view by adding a binding adapter and then importing the viewmodel into the view with a `<data>` block. But I keep getting "Cannot resolve class data" when I try to add it to my view. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

I have the following layout XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ASCImageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.531"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ASCImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/infoTextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/irf_neg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ASCImageView"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have tried to add it on all levels of the XML hierarchy. The block I try to add is:

```xml
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.domain.myApp.ASCViewModel" />
</data>
```

In my `build.gradle` on app level I have:

```
android {
    ...
        buildFeatures {
            dataBinding true
            viewBinding true
    }
```

I have also tried to add these dependencies, but I am not sure if I actually need them:

```
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.0.2'
```

I would like to use my view model to get the URL for the `ImageView` by adding `app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.myDownlodadedData.imgSrcUrl}"`. My binding adapter looks like this:

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?) {
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(imgView)
            .load(imgUri)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

If I make a new layout file and use `<layout></layout>` as root element, then I can add the `<data>` block without the error. But if I try to wrap my `drawerlayout` in a `layout` root, I get a compilation error instead that I don't understand (`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.domain.myApp.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl`). But I should be able to have a `data` block in my original XML anyway, or maybe I have misunderstood?

Any help I can get is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where you bind the viewModel??Can you please show your activity or fragment code so that I could understand in brief??

Comment: In my `MainActivity.kt` file I create the view model whith `private val viewModel: ASCViewModel by viewModels()`, and then I inflate my view binding with `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`. I try to set `binding.viewModel = viewModel` which the IDE seems to accept, but I get the error above when I try to compile. Maybe a better approach would be to use `Fragments` instead?

Comment: I had named my module with a capital letter in the beginning, which apparently you shoulldn't. So after renaming it with a lower case letter it is at least not throwing the compilation error anymore.

Comment: can you please attach your code snippet of your activity here? So that Could understand root cause of your issue

Comment: I had to add `this@MainActivity` as the `lifeCycleOwner` and now it seems to work, although I'm not sure why. Is was this the missing part?
```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel: ASCViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        ...

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.apply {
            ...
            vm = viewModel
            lifecycleOwner = this@MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this question. The problem was that I was setting the wrong activity as `lifeCycleOwner`, setting `this@MainActivity` as the lifeCycleOwner was likely what fixed it.